# Asp.Net 5 / Identity 3: Caching of Claims in the IdentityDbContext implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

While looking for a way to be able to assign and revoke roles via an admin controller for users other than the one making a request, I've implemented a custom IAuthorizeFilter that checks if Guid tag, stored as a Claim, matches to a value in the Entity Framework 7 Code First Identity table for UserClaims.

Essentials, it's this code:

```
public class RefreshUserClaimsFilterAttribute : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var User = context.HttpContext.User;
        var dbContext = context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var stampFromClaims = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(Claim => Claim.Type == "ClaimsStamp")?.Value;
        var stampFromDb = dbContext.UserClaims.Where(UserClaim => UserClaim.UserId == User.GetUserId()).ToList().FirstOrDefault(UserClaim => UserClaim.ClaimType == "ClaimsStamp")?.ClaimValue; 
        // Update claims via RefreshSignIn if necessary
    }
}
```

I'm having the problem at the line where I'm assigning `var stampFromDb`, it could be much more readable in the following way:

```
var stampFromDb = dbContext.UserClaims.FirstOrDefault(UserClaim => UserClaim.UserId == User.GetUserId() && UserClaim.ClaimType == "ClaimsStamp")?.ClaimValue;
```

That, however, gives me cached (the same values as the actual claims from  User.Identity) results and I could not find any documentation on this. My best guess is that the error is somewhere on my side, but I've never encountered such a problem before. This is the first time I'm using Asp.Net 5 and EF7. I'm using the default connection (LocalDB) to SQL Server 12.0.2000.

Is this a feature and, if yes, can it be turned off or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I'm expecting a cached result (from a Http cookie as far as I know) when I call `User.Claims` (which it does). Then I'm updating the database with `UserManager.ReplaceClaimAsync()`. Now the database entry for UserClaims has a different ClaimValue than the one cached in the cookie. However, when I'm accessing the claim as described in the question on the `ApplicationDbContext.UserClaims` DbSet, I do get the old value if I use the query mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused due to there being two different ways to create a service via dependency injection:
The sample code in my question used

```
var dbContext = context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

where it should use

```
var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The difference here is between `ApplicationServices` and `RequestServices`. It looks like the `ApplicationServices` injector does have an instance of the database context somewhere which has had the DbSet filled earlier and therefore returning cached data instead of doing a database query.